# Access <td> text on click

Tags: php, jquery, html, onclick, html-table

I want to get the text of just which table data is clicked on. i.e. get $post_no value if clicked on post_no, get the word 'description' if clicked on description. I have tried a number of ways but cannt get what i want. whats the approach?

my php code:

```
echo "<table border=1>";
        echo "<tr><th>Post No</th><th>Writer ID</th><th>Writer Name</th><th>Title</th><th>Description</th><th>Summary</th><th>Approval</th></tr>";
        while ($row=  mysqli_fetch_array($r2)){
            $post_no=$row['post_no'];
            $writer_id=$row['writer_id'];
            $writer_name=$row['writer_name'];
            $title=$row['title'];
            $description=$row['description'];
            $summary=$row['summary'];


            echo "<tr height='50' class='x"."". " '>";
            echo "<td class='r'>".$post_no."</td>";
            echo "<td class='r'>".$writer_id."</td>";
            echo "<td class='r'>".$writer_name."</td>";
            echo "<td class='r'>".$title."</td>";
            echo "<td class='r'>".'description'."</td>";
            echo "<td class='r'>".'summary'."</td>";
            echo "<td class='r'>Approve</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
```

javascript code;

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".x").each(function(i){
                $(this).click(function(){
                    console.log($(this).children().eq(i).text());
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You want the text when clicked on that column or row?

Comment: why not just point directly to `class="r"`

Comment: Not resolving you problem, but you miss some `$` near `.'description'.` and `.'summary'.`.

Comment: It will be much better to see final HTML code (which you see in browser) instead of PHP code.

Comment: @Ghost>>> pls say details

Comment: What do you mean with access? You want to retrieve the text?

Comment: @sgt> not whole text of row. just text of <td>

Comment: @mikey> yes i wanna get the text

Comment: @downvoter>> how should be the questen pattern, please?

Comment: @ParthoProtim below are the answers, they're just pointing directly to that class. you assigned every cell as `class="r"` anyway, just pick the answer you like

Comment: Note: There is not reason to bind to the row, when you can target your TDs directly with a selector.

Comment: thank u all. now it works. but i dont get how this question can be downvoted, which is obvious to understand. answered rightly by many people proofs, its obvious to understand.

Comment: You can probably avoid further down-votes if you pick one answer and stop apparently selecting them all. I am getting dizzy watching the green tick bounce around the page! :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie> so what should i do?

Comment: Decide which is the best answer for you and pick one. Stop selecting over and over as you will just annoy everyone as they get 15 points, then have them taken away :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to know on what value you've clicked on, but the binding remains on the row?
Perfectly possible:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".x").click(function(event){
            console.log(event.target); //Log where you clicked
            console.log($(event.target).text());
        });
    });
```

Why should this work?
In the event handler that we add to the clicking event when we click the elements with class x (every row), we pass a reference to the event itself.
In this reference we have access to a lot of information about the event, like in this case the target. The target is the Element where there is really clicked.

Because Javascript works with event bubbling, you do not need to set the handler on every element, but you can set it on a top level (even on 'body' would work), and with this (event.target) you can see where the user really clicked.

Because we now know the element that the user clicked, we can pass that reference to a jQuery object ($(event.target)) and utilise the text() function.

Comment: an `each` is seldom required on a jQuery object for adding event handling!

Comment: Just copied the OP code, and added the lines that will make it work.

Comment: That is not an excuse for propagating unnecessary code :)

Comment: True that, so I removed it :)

Comment: and how can i get the <th> text when clicked on <td>

Comment: Put the event handler not in the "x"-class, but on the table.

Answer (score 2):

So you just want the value of `$post_no` if you click on the according div? Then why don't you just bind the event on that class?

```
$(".r").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).text()) 
});
```

Since people continue to downvote this - for whatever reason - here you go, fiddle. If i do something wrong, tell me and don't just downvote.

https://jsfiddle.net/LcbwL85m/

Comment: So, to whoever is downvoting this - mind an explanation?

Comment: @YUNOWORK Strategical downvotes, I have seen this behaviour more on this forum and you can actually find posts (not on this forum necessarily) about how to strategical downvote...I think it is stupid and not in line with the concept of Stackoverflow, but yeah that is my opinion...

Answer (score 2):

I would do this

```
$('.x').click(function (e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    console.log($target.text());
});
```

Comment: Basically, you don't need to use .each() because the $('.x') selector has already selected "each" of them already. We put "e" as an "argument" in the function to reference the Event of the Click. We then assign the target of the click event, IE, the thing you clicked on, to a variable. ( you can skip this step however ) and then we can do what ever we want with the target! In this case, log it's text.

Comment: Also that variable has a $ sign before it because it's just something I do to remind me if a variable is an HTML element or not.

Comment: @JoshStevenson `$target` is jQuery's object, not DOM Element.

Comment: I know, I'm explaining it in simple terms for Partho. But thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<table border=1>";
        echo "<tr><th>Post No</th><th>Writer ID</th><th>Writer Name</th><th>Title</th><th>Description</th><th>Summary</th><th>Approval</th></tr>";
        while ($row=  mysqli_fetch_array($r2)){
            $post_no=$row['post_no'];
            $writer_id=$row['writer_id'];
            $writer_name=$row['writer_name'];
            $title=$row['title'];
            $description=$row['description'];
            $summary=$row['summary'];


            echo "<tr height='50' class='x"."". " '>";
            echo "<td class='r'>".$post_no."</td>";
            echo "<td class='r'>".$writer_id."</td>";
            echo "<td class='r'>".$writer_name."</td>";
            echo "<td class='r'>".$title."</td>";
            echo "<td class='r'>".$description."</td>";
            echo "<td class='r'>".$summary."</td>";
            echo "<td class='r'>Approve</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
```

// jquery part

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('click','.r',function(event){
               event.preventDefault();
               var td_txt = $(this).text();
              console.log(td_txt);
            //or you can use alert.
           });
        });
    </script>
```

the php values of 'description' and 'summary' were not concatenated properly.
in the jquery part you can use alert as well to get the value of respective `td`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#table_test").find("td").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      alert($(this).text());  
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_test" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Three</td>
    <td>Four</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

With this code, you can alert the value of each td.

**This code use .each(), which is not advisable, better use `event.target` on click on `table`.**

Comment: Never use an `each` for event handling when *you do not need to*!

Comment: My bad, I didn't know the use of `event.target`. Learnt something today ! Thank you

Comment: @Zeratops `this` points to element, for which event was triggered, when `$("#table_test td").on("click", function() {` is used too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why everyone is going for complicated solutions. Just use a selector that targets the elements you desire:

```
$("tr.x td.r").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

or even just:

```
$(".r").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

### Dynamic elements:

If you are after something more efficient, you can use a delegated event handler. This has the advantage that it will still work if items are added dynamically to the table:

```
$("table").on('click', 'td.r', function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

This works by listening for events (in this case `click`) to bubble up to the non-changing ancestor element, *then* it applies the jQuery filter (in this case `td.r`) to just the elements in the bubble-chain. It *then* applies the function to just the element that caused the event. The upshot of all this is that the elements only need to exist at event time and not when the event was registered.

The target of the delegated event should be a non-changing ancestor element. In this example I just chose `table`. If nothing is close/convenient the default to use is `document` (do not use `body` as it has a bug that can stop mouse events responding)