# How to pass multiple search parameters in array for searching in php

Tags: php, arrays

Iam writing my code in php and my array looks like this

```
$arr=Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Business_name] => 1847(Jumeirah)
        [Business_id] => 1422
        [Business_Locality] => Jumeirah
        [Locality_id] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Business_name] => 1847 Mens Salon(Trade Centre)
        [Business_id] => 42
        [Business_Locality] => Trade Centre
        [Locality_id] => 4
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Business_name] => 1847 Mens Salon(Mirdif)
        [Business_id] => 1565
        [Business_Locality] => Mirdif
        [Locality_id] => 28
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Business_name] => 1847 Mens Salon(City  Walk)
        [Business_id] => 494
        [Business_Locality] => City  Walk
        [Locality_id] => 77
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [Business_name] => 1847 Mens Salon(Dubai Marina)
        [Business_id] => 44
        [Business_Locality] => Dubai Marina
        [Locality_id] => 3
    ))
```

Now if i want to get data who have Locality_id=2,but if i want to search for data with locality_id=2 and locality_id=3.So when the result set comes back it should only have data for locality_id=2 and locality_id=3.
How do i do that.

This is the code i have written till now

```
function search($array, $key, $value)
 {
$results = array();

if (is_array($array)) {
    if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value) {
        $results[] = $array;
    }

    foreach ($array as $subarray) {
        $results = array_merge($results, search($subarray, $key, $value));
    }
}

return $results;
   }



   print_r(search($arr, 'Locality_id', '2'));
```

Comment: I can't understand what do you need

Comment: So, this is not free coding service. see your code and efforts which you had tried to do that.

Comment: And what you have tried so far. Show your efforts to get better result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This'll help you to gain your result

```
$check = array(2,3);
$result_array = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($arr as $itemKey => $itemValue) {

        if (in_array($itemValue['Locality_id'],$check)) {
            $result_array[$i]['Business_name'] = $itemValue['Business_name'];
            $result_array[$i]['Business_id'] = $itemValue['Business_id'];
            $result_array[$i]['Business_Locality'] = $itemValue['Business_Locality'];
            $result_array[$i]['Locality_id'] = $itemValue['Locality_id'];
        }else{
            continue;
        }
        $i++;
}
print_r($result_array);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Business_name] => 1847(Jumeirah) [Business_id] => 1422 [Business_Locality] => Jumeirah [Locality_id] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [Business_name] => 1847 Mens Salon(Dubai Marina) [Business_id] => 44 [Business_Locality] => Dubai Marina [Locality_id] => 3 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Smells like homework. But whatever. If i understood your question correctly, this should do it:

```
$lookingFor = array(2,3);

foreach($thisArray as $key => $value) {
    foreach($lookingFor as $looking) {
        if(in_array($looking, $value['Locality_id'])) {
            $output[] = $value;
            continue;
        }
    }
}

print_r($output);
```

I didn't test this yet, my dev is down atm, but it should work or be at least the correct direction. You should be able to adjust the code yourself.

Comment: you say: *If i understood your question correctly,*. So, why you don't make a comment first in the question? I advice, you can be downvoted

Comment: Simple reason, i think i understood it. Also, i do not really care about downvotes. I'm not here to gain a lot of reputation. I'm here to share my knowledge and help with problems. Also, you get downvoted sometimes for no reason at all so other people can push their own answer up top.

Comment: you say: *Also, you get downvoted sometimes for no reason at all so other people can push their own answer up top*. I really detest this kind of people, This behavior is insane.

Comment: It might be insane, but it is reality, even though it's not the purpose of this website. I experienced it several times on my own posts, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770077/access-td-text-on-click/29770142#29770142

Comment: you get my +1 in the link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770077/access-td-text-on-click/29770142#29770142) I can't understand this type of behavior.

Comment: Something like, yes. Some people obviously aren't here to share their knowledge, but getting as much reputation as possible. So, why not downvoting the "competition"? You only lose 2 rep for a downvote, but receive 10 for an upvote on your own question, so 8 rep win. Thanks for your upvote btw, even though that was not my intention. :)

Comment: I know, it's just an act of solidarity ;-)

Comment: I'm with you @YUNOWORK even I've been through _Strategical downvotes_

Comment: "Smells like homework" rofl.its nice to see some humor on stack oveflow.The line made my day

Comment: @RaviKant If you want read something funny read what happens with the answers in this question http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/13272/12112

Comment: haha that was funnier.I really like this site but dont like down votes,people make mistakes,i made one and rectified it.My bad.But in all people are helpful